# Xpath expression issue

Tags: xpath

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter an email address</div>
```

I want to write a XPath expression such that if the div contains `Please enter an email address` and class is exact equal to `alert alert-danger` it should return me the element. Currently I have this xpath `"//*[contains(text(),'Please enter an email address')]"`

How do I add this condition so it only returns if the class attribute is `"alert alert-danger"`. If it contains "alert alert-danger hello" it should not return i.e it should do a n `equal` match and not a `LIKE` match

Comment: Adding a predicate `[@class eq 'alert alert-danger']` should do, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//div[@class="alert alert-danger"][.="Please enter an email address"]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'and' and chain the conditionals, for example:

```
"//*[contains(text(), 'Please enter an email address') and @class='alert alert-danger']"
```